# Why is 1 newton meter=.225 lbs force?

Tags: forces, newtonian-gravity, work, weight, unit-conversion

This is a general question regarding force (mass x acceleration).  I understand 1N =1kg mass x 1 m per second sq) all this basically tells me is that the force is proportionally increased and decreased when i increased or decrease the mass or force or both.  However my question that I have been wondering is why is the actual force of a newton what it is.  I know 1 newton equals .225 pounds because .1020 kg of mass accelerated at 9.8 m/s sq equals a newton and I can easily convert the force of kg mass into pound force since 1kg mass= 1kg mass force at gravity on earth .  So why is it .225 pounds of force per newton.  Why not any other number?  I know it would change the force proportionally to the force of accelerating any matter in the universe, but I am just wondering why it is that amount of force .225 for 1 newton.  Is this just an "ACCEPTED CONSTANT" that doesn't change with no reason?

Answer (score 5):

They're just different units of force.  If you hold a one kilogram object in your hand, its weight is $1\ \mathrm{kg}\times9.8\ \mathrm{m/s^2} = 9.8\ \mathrm N$.  If you choose to measure the weight of that object in imperial units, you will find that it weighs about $2.2\ \mathrm{lbs}$.

Therefore,
$$9.8\ \mathrm N = 2.2\ \mathrm{lbs}$$
so
$$ 1\ \mathrm N = \frac{2.2}{9.8}\ \mathrm{lbs} \approx 0.224\ \mathrm{lbs}$$

It's just like inches vs. centimeters – they are two different units for measuring length, and 1 inch equals 2.54 centimeters.

Answer (score 0):

It's important to remember that all units, like "Newtons", "Joules", "Power", are all derived from a few basic units.  In this case, the only basic units involved are:

time (measured in seconds).
distance (measured in meters).
mass (measured in kilograms).

For the above three, the units (seconds, meters, and kilograms) are **entirely arbitrary**.  They are completely made up by humans.

Now let's derive from these basic units:

velocity = distance / time.  So, unit of velocity is:  meters/seconds

acceleration = velocity / time.  So, unit of acceleration is: meters/seconds/seconds, or just meters/seconds^2

Newton = mass * acceleration.  So, unit of Newton is: kg * meters/seconds^2

Here we find that:

N = kg*meters/seconds^2

So, a "Newton" is just equal to a combination of our three basic (arbitrary) units (kilograms, meters, and seconds).  The value of a Newton was not determined based on 0.225 pounds.  A Newton just happens to be equal to 0.225 pounds ("Newton" and "Pounds" are just different units that measure force).

Answer (score 0):

That number most likely comes from the most commonly used factors for converting the types of weight from kgs... For N it would be acceleration due to gravity which is 9.80665 or more commonly 9.8 and for lbs it is about 2.205 the decimal is actually much longer but approximately that... 2.205/9.8=.225 i just really dont like that because they are rounded to different decimal places so its really more like either 2.2/9.8=.224480796 ...... Or 2.205/9.807 =.2248394...... Which is also bad because mathematically  you shouldn't round until your final answer but it ends up rounding to .225 reason for that specific decimal is probably either what i said at first or because in math we love rounding to the thousandths place